# Overwrite content of new generated file

Tags: python, file, overwrite

The code generates a file every 30 seconds with the date/time and then types the 'key' in self.log into it. The problem is when the new file gets generated and 'key' gets typed into that it just appends itself to the bottom and doesn't overwrite the old content in the newly generated file.
Would appreciate your help :)

```
   def report(self):
        if self.log:
            print(self.log)
            starttime = time.time()
            while True:
                timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                fileloc = f'C:/logging/pylogger/{timestr}.txt'
                with open(fileloc, mode='w') as f:
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.truncate()
                    for key in self.log:
                        f.write(key)
                    time.sleep(30.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 30.0))
```

Comment: `mode='w'` overwrites the content. No need to `seek` and `truncate`.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not fully clear to me, but if I correctly understood you need to remove the elements from the list once written:

```
def report(self):
    if self.log:
        print(self.log)
        starttime = time.time()
        while True:
            timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            fileloc = f'C:/logging/pylogger/{timestr}.txt'
            with open(fileloc, mode='w') as f:
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                for key in self.log:
                    f.write(key)
                    self.log.remove(key)
                time.sleep(30.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 30.0))
```

Just add `self.log.remove(key)` in your for loop, so the values are removed from the list once written and when you reach the next cycle after 30 seconds the new file will contains only the new values.